# Как быстро склеить зависимые записи в одну строку

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, office-interop

Допустим, есть 2 таблицы:

1)Должность

2)Персонал, которая ссылается на Должность.

На одну запись Должность могут приходится несколько записей из Персонал.

Задача обновить [Весь персонал] в Должность склеенными в одну строчку зависимыми записями из Персонал.

Допустим приходится на 1 запись приходится 2 строчки ФИО из Персонал, мы их склеиваем и записываем в родительскую запись Должность.

Как это сделать быстро? Используется БД Access.

Сейчас я использую Interop, открываю RecordSet из Должность, и иду сверху вниз, и на каждую запись я открываю второй RecordSet из запроса 'Select PID,FIO From [Персонал] where PID='rst.fields[ID].value и иду сверху вниз и склеиваю значения, а потом возвращаю и обновляю их в первом RecordSet и мне кажется, что слишком это тормознуто и можно как то быстрее сделать это.

Наверное, через ADO.NET было бы быстрее, но мне кажется, что если БД Access будет здоровой, то слишком жирно все в память грузить разом...

**UPD:**
Если все таки загрузить все в память и работать через ADO.NET, я получу значительный выигрыш в скорости?

Comment: от Access отказаться никак?

Comment: @Mirdin, производственная необходимость...

Comment: не гуд, алгоритм можно ускорить перенеся вычисления на сервер, и скорее всего тут подойдет практически любой MSSQL, MySQL и пр. Но Acces - это бд для хранения телефонных номеров.

Comment: Вопрос интересный. Не хотите задать его в более общем виде(имею ввиду поправить заголовок)? "Как в ms-access сконкатенировать строки в группе?", например. Так вопрос, мне кажется, будет полезней. Я понимаю, что вам не обязательно решать это средствами sql+vb, но всё же..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно написать VB функцию, которая будет склеивать строку.
Подробно можно прочитать тут:

http://hiprog.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=334&Itemid=35

Тело функции:

```
Public Function UnionStr1(ID, Fam)
Static IDOld, FamUnion
If IDOld <> ID Then
IDOld = ID
FamUnion = Null
End If

FamUnion = (FamUnion + ", ") & Fam
UnionStr1 = FamUnion
End Function
```

Пример запроса:

```
Select ID, Last(UnionStr1(ID,Fam)) AS FamUnion FROM Tab1
GROUP BY ID;
```

В той же статье есть интересный способ. Только средствами ms-access sql, с промежуточной таблицей. Хотя возможно в вашем случае её роль сыграет таблица Person(должностей).
Выглядит примерно так:

```
Метод 3. Заполнение таблицы при помощи запросов (по Митину).
http://c85.cemi.rssi.ru/Access/AnsPointDetail.idc?QID=14147

Оригинальный и неочевидный метод. 
Выполняется с помощью двух запросов.
1. Запись в Tab2 уникальных ID без фамилий.
Текст запроса WriteID:
INSERT INTO Tab2 (ID) Select DISTINCT ID FROM Tab1;

2. Запись списков фамилий.
Текст запроса TabUnion5:
UPDATE Tab2 INNER JOIN Tab1 On Tab2.ID = Tab1.ID 
Set Tab2.FamUnion = ([Tab2].[FamUnion]+", ") & [Tab1].[Fam];

Оценка скорости: по-видимому, работает быстрее метода 1 за счет отсутствия вызова специальных функций.
Недостаток: "Однако в T-SQL это непрокатывает" (Митин).
```

Надо побаловаться, выглядит интересно.

**UPD:**
Смысл в том, что из-за "глупости" `ms-access` `SET` будет выполнятся столько раз, сколько записей в присоединённой таблице(не той, которая апдейтится). Из-за "умности" `T-SQL`, в `T-SQL` этот способ работать не будет.

К минусам этого способа я бы ещё добавил потребность в сопровождении при переходе на новую версию `access`. Если `MS` решат приблизить хоть чуть-чуть `ms-access` к стандарту `ANSI-SQL`, этот метод может перестать работать.

С другой стороны, может они и для конкатенации строк что-нибудь сделают:) Хотя в этом вопросе даже `MS SQL Server` обделён вниманием до сих пор. `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle` это давно умеют.

Comment: MS SQL тоже умеет делать конкатенацию.

Comment: @Mirdin, имеете ввиду FOR XML PATH('') - это не то. Данный способ практически всегда подразумевает самосоединение. А если нужно сконкатенировать несколько столбцов - то несколько самосоединений. У MS SQL нет агрегатной функции, которая делала бы это. Её не так сложно найти в интете, написанную на CLR, но из коробки не умеет... В трёх других СУБД есть свои агрегатные функции. MS SQL до 2012 года даже накопительный итог не мог считать... И FOR XML - всё-таки предназначен не для этого. Просто выбора другово нет...

Comment: да, имею в виду FOR XML PATH(''), для нечасто встречающейся задачи (ну лично в моем опыте) вполне то.

Comment: >> MS SQL до 2012 года даже накопительный итог не мог считать... УЖОС,  УЖОС,  УЖОС... вы все таки с БД, а не с электронной таблицей работаете :)

Comment: @Mirdin, не знаю, какого характера опыт работы у вас. Я писал огромное количество отчетов - в моей работе накопительный итог и конкатенация по группе были очень востребованы. И то, что MS этого не умеет - сильно замедляло работу запросов. Так что да, "УЖОС". С 2012 сервером всё стало гораздо более приятней. Это был большой шаг вперёд.

Comment: @pegoopik, способ работает и достаточно быстро. А что делать если какого-то поля, которое плюсуется нет и тогда получаются лишние запятые. Может быть есть хитрый способ, что бы их убрать?

Comment: @iluxa1810, отфильтруйте эти записи, так будет ещё чуть быстрее. В `WHERE` или условии соединения. Если же этот вариант не подходит, в ms-access есть аналог `CASE`, кажется так, если не напутал с функциями: `[Tab2].[FamUnion] + IIF(LEN([Tab1].[Fam]) > 0, ', ', '' )`.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы делал так:

**Допустим**

```
в таблице персонал(Person) есть три поля: Person_ID, Person_FIO, Position_ID
в таблице должность(Position) есть три поля: Position_ID, Position_Name, Position_StaffList
```

Для начала пишем запрос для DataReader'a (если я правильно понимаю это C# аналог Recordset из Basic):

```
SELECT pos.Position_ID, pos.Position_Name, prs.Person_FIO 
FROM Position AS pos
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Person AS prs ON pos.Position_ID = prs.Position_ID
ORDER BY pos.Position_ID, prs.Person_FIO;
```

И служебный класс

```
internal class Pos
{
    public Pos()
    {
        StaffList = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public int? Position_ID {get; set;}
    public string Position_Name {get; set;}
    public StringBuilder StaffList {get; set;}
}
```

Открываем ридер для нашего запроса.

```
List<Pos> positions = new List<Pos>();
int previos_pos = -1;

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    int id;
    string position_name;
    string fio;
    Pos current;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        position_name = reader.GetString(1);
        fio = reader.GetString(2);   

        if (id != previos_pos)
        {
            current = new Pos();
            positions.Add(current);
            current.Position_ID = id;
            current.Position_Name = position_name;
            current.StaffList.Append(fio); 
        } 
        else
        {
            current.StaffList.AppendFormat("{0},{1}"
               , current.StaffList,
               , fio
               ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Закрываем наш ридер. Теперь у нас есть заполненный список positions и остается только обновить из него вашу таблицу позиции. Так как мы не ддосим базу промежуточными запросами (что может быть действительно долго если позиций много), то мы должны получить некоторое ускорение.

Comment: Ваше решение интересно, но не решает важную проблему: " если БД Access будет здоровой, то слишком жирно все в память грузить разом...". Если есть возможность обработать большой объём данных на уровне сервера - лучше это там и делать.

Comment: @pegoopik,  " если БД Access будет здоровой, то слишком жирно все в память грузить разом..." -- вот это само по себе проблема, большие данные не для Access. Кроме того грузятся в память не вся база данных, а только позиции, сколько их может быть на предприятии, сотня другая, даже для весьма крупного - это достаточно много.

Comment: В рамках текущего вопроса согласен. Плюсанул всё же)

Comment: @pegoopik, тут сам вопрос нарушает 1НФ - так что хорошего решения тут и не будет.

Comment: Нарушение 1НФ в случае с access часто оправдано:) В этом случае спорно.. Примерно настолько же, насколько спорно не установить какую-нибудь нормальную бесплатную СУБД.

Answer (score -1):

> Как это сделать быстро? Используется БД Access.

Возможно ужасно знаю способности MS Access... но предполагаю, что сделать эту задачу средствами БД Access невозможно, т.к. там слабый потенциал аналитических функций и расширений SQL запросов.

В более способных СУБД в которых язык SQL расширяют доп.аналитическими функциями, есть способы выполнить такую задачу, но даже они выглядят ужасно и криво - например в Oracle с помощью компоновки аналитических функций в нескольких подзапросах.
Поэтому для вас самый идеальный вариант тот, что вы уже делаете - сформировать запрос должностей, переходом по должностям, выполнять второй запрос для получения всех ФИО из этой должности. Обрабатывать полученные списки.

Предложенный вами вариант действий:

> Допустим приходится на 1 запись приходится 2 строчки ФИО из Персонал,
>   мы их склеиваем и записываем в родительскую запись Дожность

- это ужасное и грубое нарушение структуры данных и логики (о нормальных формах БД надо почитать). Делается вывод - у вас скорее всего неверная постановка задачи, либо неверное принятие решения для ее выполнения.

PS: поясняю.. если вы все ФИО принадлежащие для 1 должности засунете в поле этой должности, то выполняя запрос к этой должности и выводя информацию на клиенте - вы ничем не сэкономите ОЗУ, т.к. действует математическое правило "от перемены мест слагаемых сумма не меняется". Не важно получите вы эти ФИО и будете хранить в разных полях, либо в одном поле, количество байт символов не изменится, во всяком случае разница будет не заметна для ПК. Но зато когда вы будете получать список известных должностей - то объемы передаваемой информации будут расти очень быстро, что увеличит нагрузку на трафик и БД.

Лучше сформулируйте задачу поставленную перед вами, чтобы вам смогли подсказать оптимальное решение, т.к. в данном вопросе вы просите помочь вам выполнить решение которое приняли самостоятельно - но оно ошибочное.

Comment: "например в Oracle" можно написать свою агрегатную функцию. В Access тоже, но выполняться она будет на стороне клиента.